# Select multiple classes where a class attribute value begins with "xx"

Tags: html, css, wordpress, class

So I have a `<div>` which contains two classes `<div class=vc_column-inner vc_custom_1583926619313>`

I know how to select multiple classes with `.class1.class2` and how to select a class attribute value that begins with "xx" `div[class^="test"]`
My question is, is there a way to select them?

The thing is I want to select all classes with `vc_column-inner` and `vc_custom_` but all of them have different ending numbers.

(I cannot change the classes because it's predifined by Wordpress)

Comment: this is wrong !! I think you are working with visual composer plugin in wordpress and modifying a global class is not at all recommended.. Tweak around some setting in the plugin to achieve the desired result

Comment: Yeah I know but I want to select all of them and change the style from all classes... otherwise it took a long time to change each elements one by one

Comment: Anyway is there a way to select those classes? Just out of curiosity

Comment: I think you may be able to add your own class through WP setting and use that to override default global styles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a combination of class name and attribute contains selector like so:

```
div.vc_column-inner[class*="vc_custom_"] {
  /* your CSS here */
}
```